# What do these little flying drones on the Uprising map do?

Tags: overwatch

I can shoot them down, but apparently killing one doesn't give any credit in the killfeed, and it doesn't seem like there's anything they're associated with, or is there?

[image]

I only really notice them when the battle's idled about during the breaks between some of the phases, what are these and does killing them help at all?

Comment: Are they on every map?

Comment: This is a PvE event with one map.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These drones are just for show, that is it. You can shoot them down, but they are only there for lore purposes. They are supposed to just simply be drones on the enemy team. They do not cause damage or contribute at all to the enemy team.

Comment: Torb's turret seems to get distracted by them, which is unfortunate, but they've got such low health that it doesn't matter too much.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf I've also seen Torb turrets shooting randomly into the sky, but I don't think is is aiming at those drones. It is shooting at the robots that are being dropped down from above.

Comment: @MageXy Whenever the turrents aim at the sky, they always follow the robots as they drop down, so you're definitely right there. And I'd consider the fact that Torb's turret doesn't care about the drones as a pretty big indication that this answer is accurate.

Answer (score 4):

These drones don't appear to be useful for anything. I played many rounds of this new game mode last night, and shot these drones down every time I saw them (even while our payload was being attacked, much to the displeasure of my teammates). I noticed that the rubble that they leave behind doesn't appear to despawn, which is a little unusual for destructible terrain. Other than that, I did not see any score changes or any other easter eggs related to shooting down these drones.

Answer (score -2):

I heard that they drop spawns, and when I went out of my way to shoot them all, it felt like there were less